# Count the frequency of bytes in a purely functional language

Tags: functional-programming

If we had an assignment:

> Given a block of binary data, count the frequency of the bytes within it.

And you were supposed to do this in C, the answer would be trivial and reasonably fast even for larger binary blocks. **How would one go about implementing this in a purely functional language, without side effects?**

For example, if you wrote a function that accepted freqency counts for each byte and the rest of the list of bytes, and returned modified frequency counts, it would have to do awful lot of work for data set of 100M bytes.

Also, if you sorted the data and then somehow counted the amount of subsequent same-valued bytes, the sort itself would take a lot of time.

Is there a reasonable way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straightforward way to do it is indeed to pass in and return data structures mapping bytes to counts. This would probably be implemented as some kind of tree (since that's what you get out of the standard library containers, as far as I know). In pure functional programming when you're passed in a tree and you need to return a new tree with a difference in only one node, the returned tree ends up sharing almost all of its structure and data with the original tree.

There is some overhead in traversing the tree to get to the count, but since you're counting bytes the tree is only ever smaller than 256 elements, so the overhead is log(255), which is a constant. It doesn't get larger for large data sets - it doesn't change the big-oh complexity of the algorithm. That's actually true even if you use the greatest possible overhead of copying around a full 256-entry array of counts with no sharing.

If you want to optimise this, you can take advantage of the fact that the "intermediate" frequency counts are never needed except as part of the computation of the next set of counts. That means you can use various techniques for getting the implementation to use destructive updates even while you're still semantically writing functional code. An `STref` in Haskell is basically letting you do this manually.

Theoretically the compiler could notice that you're replacing a never-needed-again value with a new one, so it could do the update in place for you. I don't know whether or not any actual production ready compilers are currently able to make this optimisation.

Comment: One could do the counting with a big integer that has 256*n bits, where n is the maximum number of bits needed to count the expected amount of data.